# CRM - Fetch Multiple Attributes MetaData in c#

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm-2011, metadata, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013

I want to fetch the metadata for multiple attributes using single *CrmService* Call with the help of class "**RetrieveAttributeRequest**".

I know that we can use **EntityMetadata** to fetch all the metadata that we require related to that particular entity.

Does anybody have any idea on this class "**RetrieveAttributeRequest**" because what I found till now that we can fetch only single attribute's metadata at a time using this class.

Please suggest if possible.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [RetrieveEntityRequest](https://crmprof.wordpress.com/2013/03/13/how-to-retrieve-entity-metadata-using-net-in-microsoft-dynamics-crm-2011/) with limiting to get only attributes. The only difference is you have to use EntityFilters.Attributes passing to EntityFilters attribute of request.

Comment: Thanks, Andrii.

Yes, I have Implemented that already BTW is it posible to fetch multiple attributes metadata using "RetrieveAttributeRequest" ?

Comment: @AnishwithCRM no, it is not possible. Use RetrieveEntityRequest.